# Why does this happen when I insert a date value into a table? ERROR: value too long for type character varying(30) - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to insert a DATE type value into a table. For that to happen, I used this line of code:

```
insert into funcionario (primeiro_nome, nome_meio, ultimo_nome, cpf, data_nascimento, endereco, sexo, salario, numero_departamento)
values ('João', 'B', 'Silva', 12345678966, '19650109', 'R. das Flores, 751, São Paulo, SP', 'M', 30000, 5);
```

But when I run the script I get this message:

```
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(30)
```

The data type is set to DATE and I've also tried rewriting it in all sorts of ways, such as '1965-09-01', '1965/09/01', '1965.09.01', and so on. I have even tried to use `to_date()`

What should I do to revert this situation?

Comment: Pretty sure the error is referring to: `'R. das Flores, 751, São Paulo, SP'` as the issue is with `character varying(30)` field not a `date` field and the string has ~34 characters in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that your 'endereco' is most probably limited to 30 characters and you are trying to insert 33 characters in that column.

You can try shortening that text and see if this works. If yes, then you should maybe rethink the max size of that column in the table.